# Using Python CDK to bundle dotnet 8 code to AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am using CDK with Python and trying to build, package and deploy dotnet 8 code as a lambda function.

This python code below gets an error `Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built.`

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    Stack,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_lambda as lambda_
)
    csharp_lambda = lambda_.Function(
        self, "PythonCdkDotnetLambda",
        runtime=lambda_.Runtime.DOTNET_8,
        handler="helloworld::helloworld.Functions::ExecuteFunc",  
        code=lambda_.Code.from_asset("../path/to/src"),
    )
```

When using CDK with dotnet there is a bundling option like below where the code is built and packaged

```
       //C# Code
       var buildOption = new BundlingOptions()
       {
           Image = Runtime.DOTNET_8.BundlingImage,
           User = "root",
           OutputType = BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED,
           Command = new string[]{
          "/bin/sh",
           "-c",
           " dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools"+
           " && dotnet build"+
           " && dotnet lambda package --project-location helloworld/ --output-package /asset-output/function.zip"
           }
       };
```

How do you do this BundlingOption for Python CDK that needs to deploy a dotnet 8 lambda or how do you build .net code into the required binaries before deploying using Python CDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the following code

```
        bundling_options = {
        "command": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            " dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools"+
            " && dotnet build" +
            " && dotnet lambda package --project-location helloworld/ --output-package /asset-output/function.zip"
        ],
        "image": lambda_.Runtime.DOTNET_8.bundling_image,
        "user": "root"
    }
            
    
    csharp_lambda = lambda_.Function(
        self, "PythonCdkDotnetLambda",
        runtime=lambda_.Runtime.DOTNET_8,
        handler="helloworld::helloworld.Functions::ExecuteFunc",  
        code=lambda_.Code.from_asset("../path/to/lambda", bundling=bundling_options),
    
    )
```

Comment: I would consider using `DockerImageFunction` for better control over your environment and bundling process.